# Template struct specialization for integral/real types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I want to create validators for numbers of different kinds (integer ,floating points) e.g.:

```
typename number_validator<T>::type validator;
```

I found useful traits in the `std` i.e. `is_integral` and `is_floating_point`. How can I use those traits to specialize the template `number_validator` (it's a `struct`) ?

edit:
I'm looking for something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Enabled>
struct number_validator {};

template<typename T>
struct number_validator<T, typename enable_if<is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type> 
//this doesn't work..
{
    typedef floating_point_validator type;
};
```

Comment: What does your "validator" do?

Comment: it will validate numbers. I would prepare the `::type` to be typedefs for some specific classes with common interface (but not subclasses)

Comment: What I am asking is, how do you want to validate the numbers? Surely there is a simpler way than this.

Comment: Probably, but I am playing around with templates a bit ;)

Comment: @Kiel I wrote a little example for you it should be easy to understand if you run my code

Comment: @aaronman Your example is exactly what I was playing around when I stopped at this problem - how to use `enable_if` in template specialization?

Comment: @Kiel what do you need more specific than mine, any integral goes to the second declaration and floating point goes to the first

Comment: @Kiel If you could explain to me where my answer is lacking I could help more, but as of now not really understanding what else you need

Comment: @aaronman - see my edit - I want to get **types** depending on whether the number is integral or is floating point. I don't want to list N specializations for chars, ints, longs, doubles etc., but use the handy `is_integral` etc. traits

Comment: Thats exactly what the second part of my answer does please read

Comment: Your example works if you actualy define `floating_point_validator`.

Comment: @jrok does it? I can't make it compile under G++ 4.8

Comment: @Kiel Yes, [see for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ce1dd5c7cc773abc8631c829a5db7b33-d453f8cdb05876c21842cb19504c959f).

Comment: @jrok http://pastebin.com/mYQzUgyG no, it does not compile for me ;(

Comment: @Kiel My bad, with some corrections it is ok. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6036f1d5dc550f5805ea9da0ea8d877e-d453f8cdb05876c21842cb19504c959f). Note the default value for second parameter in primary template and the absence of second template parameter for `enable_if`.

Comment: @jrok wow, nice. Can you compare your solution to the one from elmes ? (it seems similar)..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for, i.e. *tag dispatching*:

```
template<typename T, bool = is_integral<T>::value>
struct number_validator {};

template<typename T>
struct number_validator<T, true> 
{
    typedef integral_validator type;
};

template<typename T>
struct number_validator<T, false> 
{
    typedef floating_point_validator type;
};
```

This assumes that you really operate on numbers, so the types are always either integral or floating point.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need those in this case, you could actually just specialize the templates like this.

```
template <typename T>
struct number_validator;
template <>
struct number_validator<float>;

template <>
struct number_validator<int>;

template <>
struct number_validator<double>;
```

This will specialize your number validator for each type, this requires you to list all the integral and floating point types. You could also do something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value,T>::type func(T t) { 
    std::cout << "You got a floating point" << std::endl;
    return t;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,T>::type func(T t) { 
    std::cout << "You got an Integral" <<std::endl;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    float f = func(1.0);
    int a = func(2);
}
```

Comment: This could actually work, but can you remove `auto` (c++03 here) ? Well, you define functions that return vales, I'd prefer to use the code how I wrote in my question (as variable declaration), but your solution would suffice if no `auto` was used.

Comment: I could remove auto, but you tagged your question c++11 and is_integral is c++11

Comment: @Kiel there it's that simple

Comment: hah, yeah this is simple. Change `main` to a template function that works on T, not on arbitrary int or float. See in my question - the declaration includes `<T>` and not int ;)

Comment: @Kiel not sure what your asking you can't template main

Comment: I've modified your answer so you can see what I mean. The template func should operate on `T` and, if possible, not use `auto`

Comment: @Kiel sorry still confused, would be simpler if you just said what's wrong with mine (which doesn't use auto anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with integer numbers:

```
template <typename T, bool isIntegral = std::is_integral<T>::value>
struct number_validator
{
   typedef WhatEverType type;
};

template <typename T>
struct number_validator<T, true>
{
    typedef WhatEverTypeInt type;
};
```

The second specialization will be chosen if it is an integer, but I don't know what to do if it is a floating point or other type.